# Custom button on account list view to assign child records to parent

Tags: button

We upload lists of accounts/contacts often. There are occasions when we upload a list that includes a new location for an account we already have in the system. I would like to be able to mass assign these accounts to the parent. I was thinking of a simple button, but not sure how to construct the code?

Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Shannon

Comment: Could you please explain some more. Are you trying to change parent of account from this button?. Could you explain what you meant by new location for account?

Comment: A few questions: what tool is used to upload Accounts/Contacts? What defines a 'location'? What is the 'parent' of an Account that is being assigned (another Account)?

Answer (score 4):

- Click on the tab where you have or will create the list view. In this
  example, it's Contact
  [image]
- Click Create New View
  [image]
- Give the view a List View Name and Unique Name
  [image]
- For the filter criteria, select what would comprise the view and this is the most important part: YOU MUST ADD A FILTER FOR THE RECORD TYPE IF THE OBJECT INCLUDES RECORD TYPES. You can only bulk update from list view if all the results are from the same record type. You must set a filter to insure this. Even if the object has just one record type and it's your default for all records, you must filter for record type in order to edit a list view.
  [image]
- Add the fields that will display in the view. Make sure the field you want to change is included.
  [image]
- Save the view. Now when you mouse over a field, you should see an edit icon.
  [image]
- Click the box at the top of the list to select all the records. If there are more records than can fit on a single screen, you may need to repeat this process multiple times.
  [image]
- Now, Double click on any of the values in the column you wish to change. Doesn't matter which one. You'll get the screen as shown. Enter the value you wish to change all the records to, and select the radio button for "All X selected records." Click Save.
  [image]
- Now click the refresh button and all records should show the new value saved for each
  [image]

  click [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003911) for more info on inline editing in a list view